# Add a button in UIScrollView from the UI when there is no more space to work with

Tags: ios, cocoa

I am new to iOS dev and I was wondering,

Lets say I am working in a `UIScrollView` in XCode. I am adding all the elements with the graphic interface.

Now I ran out of space in my default screen to place a Button at the bottom of my `UIScrollView` without having to overlap another element.

I know I could add another button at the bottom coding it. But is it possible to do it from the UI? If possible, How?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is a problem i could never understand. there should be an intuitive way to do this in IB/SB. Instead, what you need to do is drag the scrollview up in the viewcontroller, so that you get more space on the bottom. now expand the scrollview and place your buttons.
but beware: if you run your app now, the srollview will be set to the bottom. you have to set the contentsize manually and scroll it back up in code for it to work as expeted.
there really should be a simpler way.

Comment: Don't have to do it manually - simply drag the scroll view back to top so that it's top aligns with screen or alternatively, set x to 0 in properties panel. But I agree it's a fairly convoluted way.